# Why won't XPath retrieve specific class from html?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xpath

Here is the example html I'm trying to parse:

```
<div class="MyFirstClass">
    the content I am able to retrieve
</div>
<div class="MySecondClass MyThirdClass" id="my_id">
    the content I want to retrieve
</div>
```

Inspecting the element on Google Chrome, the second div is `div#my_id.MySecondClass.MyThirdClass`.

This is the Java code I am using to parse. While `content1` is in fact "the content I am able to retrieve", I am getting `content2` to be `null` instead of the expected "the content I want to retrieve".

```
XPathExpression expression1 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MyFirstClass ')]");
String content1 = expression1.evaluate(document);
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClass ')]");
String content2 = expression2.evaluate(document);
```

I have tried all of the below variations for `expressions2`, but all of them make `content2` be `null`.

```
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MyThirdClass ')]");
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClass MyThirdClass ')]");
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClassMyThirdClass ')]");
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClass.MyThirdClass ')]");
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//DIV[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClass\\.MyThirdClass ')]");
XPathExpression expression2 = Xpath.compile("//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClass\\.MyThirdClass ')]");
```

What should `expression2` be so that `content2` contains the expected "the content I want to retrieve"?

Comment: Which Java XPath API is that (`Xpath.queryText`)?

Comment: Oops. That is my own function on top of the API. Fixing the question back to XPath API.

Comment: And normally XPath and element or attribute selection is case-sensitive so using `div` instead of `DIV` is a start.

Comment: When I correct the case of the element name then `//div[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '),' MySecondClass ')]` in http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Z3 selects the element.

Comment: You might want to construct a minimal but complete code sample, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.